# Including module in file vs. in class (Ruby Mixins): What is better?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby I want to put some helpers in an extra-module and file. I will use it at the model-level, so i put

```
include MyHelper
class Shop
  ...
end
```

I now realize this can also be done like so:

```
class Shop
  include MyHelper
  ...
end
```

Can anyone explain me more about the differences? Is the second version always the better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case you include the helper in the global namespace. I can't think of a case in which that is a good idea.

In the latter case you include the helper in the "namespace" of the class. The (instance) methods defined in the module are now available to instances of the `Shop` class.